# How to debug the loading of an iOS Cordova plugin?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, plugins

I am working on the development of a Cordova plugin which encapsulate a messenger framework for iOS and Android platform.
When adding this plugin to the app project, ionic Cordova build fine and execution of the iOS app launch without problem.
My problem is the `deveiceready` event is not fired and no plugin is loaded as if the loading system had just quit silently, no logs at all…
If I remove this plugin, `devireceready` fired and others plugins loads fine

I've tried :

- rewrite the native iOS implementation from Swift 3 to ObjC
- not adding this plugin,
- adding only this plugin and remove others
- drink less coffee
- drink more coffee

**plugin.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        id="cordova-plugin-lithium"
        version="0.1">
    <name>Lithium SMM Response messenger</name>
    <description>Cordova Lithium SMM Response messenger Plugin</description>
    <keywords>cordova,smm,lithium,response,messenger</keywords>

    <js-module src="www/LithiumMessenger.js" name="LithiumMessenger">
        <clobbers target="cordova.plugins.LithiumMessenger" />
    </js-module>

    <platform name="ios">
        <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/widget">
            <feature name="LithiumMessenger">
                <param name="ios-package" value="LithiumMessenger"/>
                <param name="onload" value="true" />
            </feature>
        </config-file>
        <header-file src="src/ios/LithiumMessenger.h" />
        <source-file src="src/ios/LithiumMessenger.m" />
        <framework src="src/ios/Lithium.framework" custom="true" embed="true" />
    </platform>
</plugin>
```

**LithiumMessenger.m**

```
#import "LithiumMessenger.h"

@implementation LithiumMessenger

- (void)messengerInit:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command {
    NSLog(@"ok");
    CDVPluginResult *pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult: pluginResult callbackId: command.callbackId];
}
@end
```

**LithumMessenger.js**

```
const exec = require('cordova/exec'),
const nativePluginName = 'LithiumMessenger';

exports.init = function(arg0, success, error) {
  exec(success, error, nativePluginName, "messengerInit", [arg0]);
}
```

It would be appreciable to have some light on a possible way of solving this issue and also on how to debug the Cordova loading process of a plugin

Comment: From what I can see in your code, your JS is calling `init` but the native function is called `messengerInit` which would lead to a runtime exception.I would debug your iOS project in Xcode. Place runtime breakpoints on the native code. Also check the Xcode console log for errors.

Comment: thanks, I corrected it. That doesn't fix the problem since this part of code is not loaded (no breakpoint is hit)